# How we can check in our program multithreading is working in our program or not?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, performance

I have source code and multithreading is enabled in that code. I checked with ps -eLf command its showing number of threads list, but i think load its not distributed in all the threads.so i want to know how we can check the load is distributed in all the threads or not.

According to me complete load is going to single thread.

Actually i want to improve the performance of my code.

I am using RHEL5.4 linux OS. Programming Language is C.

if anyone knows, please let me know.....

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "the complete load"?

Comment: Try profiling tools file gprof.

Comment: Really, you should build some kind of reporting or logging capacity into your program, so that it can tell you how many requests have been serviced by each thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this:

```
ps -p PID_OF_YOUR_PROCESS -L -o pid,tid,pcpu,state,nlwp,args
```

You will see something like this as output:

```
  PID   TID %CPU S NLWP COMMAND
 2305  2305  3.5 S    5 /usr/bin/cinnamon
 2305  2325  0.0 S    5 /usr/bin/cinnamon
 2305  2326  0.0 S    5 /usr/bin/cinnamon
 2305  2327  0.0 S    5 /usr/bin/cinnamon
 2305  2721  0.0 S    5 /usr/bin/cinnamon
```

TID is the thread id. You can see the cpu percentage of each thread.

Hope that answers your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Using `top`'s option `H` would help.

Please see `man top` for details.